# Check checkbox based on variable value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I'm struggling with a checkbox. I want the checkbox to be checked depending on a variable coming from the database. I can see the value in my console, so it's dynamically filled, but I can't have the checkbox checked.

I tried 2 things:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
$('input[name="OPTIN_NEWSLETTER_STARTER_INDEPENDANT"]').each(function(index) {
        if ($(this).val() == 
"%%OPTIN_NEWSLETTER_STARTER_INDEPENDANT%%")
            ($(this).prop('checked', true));
    });
```

And

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var checkBox = 
[
     ["OPTIN_NEWSLETTER_STARTER_INDEPENDANT", 
"%%OPTIN_NEWSLETTER_STARTER_INDEPENDANT%%"],
];

for (var i = 0; i < checkBox.length; i++) {
        if (checkBox[i][1] == "Yes") {
            if ($('input[name="' + checkBox[i][0] + '"]')) 
            {
                $('input[name="' + checkBox[i][0] + 
'"]').prop("checked", true).change();
            }
        }
    };
```

This is my html checkbox:

```
<label class="yesNoCheckboxLabel">
                                        <input type="checkbox" 
name="OPTIN_NEWSLETTER_STARTER_INDEPENDANT" id="control_COLUMN136" 
label="OPTIN_NEWSLETTER_STARTER_INDEPENDANT" 
value="%%OPTIN_NEWSLETTER_STARTER_INDEPENDANT%%" 
checked="">OPTIN_NEWSLETTER_STARTER_INDEPENDANT</label>
```

It would be great to have someone's insights, thanks!

Kind regards,
Loren

Comment: $(this).prop('checked', true) should work. Could you provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example ? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I tested your code and it is working as you described how you want it to work; **except** that the first `document.ready()` block that you pasted, had incomplete closing brace and parenthesis, so I had to correct it. Are you sure that was not the cause and thus you had an error on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your case locally and It's working fine may be you are lacking some where else and make sure use `attr` in order to set value for jquery 1.5 or below

For jquery 1.5 or below

```
 ($(this).prop('checked', true));
```

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
$('input[name="vehicle1"]').each(function(index) {

        if ($(this).val() == 
"vehicle1")
            ($(this).prop('checked', true));
    });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle1" value="vehicle1"> I have a bike<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle1" value="vehicle1"> I have a car 
</form>
```

and last thing make sure that value must be same for this condition

```
$(this).val() == "vehicle1"
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm afraid I just misplaced my <script> tags, it's working indeed :)